# Add hash element to array in ruby script

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I have ruby code which generate JSON of k8s images

```rb
old_versions_json = "[]"
versions_list = JSON.parse(old_versions_json)
versions_list.push("#{namespace}")
c = versions_list.find { |h| h['name'] == name }
# If the service doesn't exist in the configmap yet, add it
if c.nil?
  puts("[WARNING] service #{name}:#{version} is not present in the configmap.  Adding it.")
  versions_list.push({ "name" => name, "version" => version })
end
```

This is how the JSON structure is coming now.

```json
[
  "medusa-dev",
  {
    "name": "pdtk/gravity-device-data-service",
    "version": "3d-dev-1.0.29"
  },
  {
    "name": "pdtk/medusa_dooku",
    "version": "3d-dev-1.1.11"
  }
]
```

**expected output**

```json
{
  "medusa-dev": [
      {
        "name": "pdtk/gravity-device-data-service",
        "version": "3d-dev-1.0.29"
      },
      {
        "name": "pdtk/medusa_dooku",
        "version": "3d-dev-1.1.11"
      }
 ]
}
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `old_versions_json`? If it is just empty array, why did you parse it? If it is some really JSON please add it to the question

Answer (score 1):

It's because `versions_list` is an array. You want it to be a map with a key of `medusa-dev` that maps to an array, which you can then push elements onto.

```rb
old_versions_json = "{}"

versions_list = JSON.parse(old_versions_json)
versions_list[namespace] = []

c = versions_list[namespace].find { |h| h['name'] == name }

# If the service doesn't exist in the configmap yet, add it
if c.nil?
  puts("[WARNING] service #{name}:#{version} is not present in the configmap.  Adding it.")
  versions_list[namespace].push({ "name" => name, "version" => version })
end
```

Btw I don't know why you provide JSON and then immediately parse it when you could just provide a literal from the start:

```rb
versions_list = { namespace => [] }
```

Comment: Looks like `versions_list = {}` is enough, don't need to parse empty object

Comment: Thank you so much  I am able to get this output
`code`
{
  "pdtk_dev": [
    {
      "name": "ecr-k8s-secret-creator",
      "version": "latest"
    }
  ]
}{
  "medusa_dev": [
    {
      "name": "pdtk/medusa_dooku",
      "version": "3d-dev-1.1.11"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Still when I checked json structure is not valid  for multiple values.
Everything should be in a single array but instead ruby is creating separate arrays for each namespace

**Valid structure**
{ "pdtk_dev": [ { "name": "ecr-k8s-secret-creator", "version": "latest" } ] ,
  "medusa_dev": [ { "name": "pdtk/medusa_dooku", "version": "3d-dev-1.1.11" } ] }

could you please suggest on this.

Comment: @mechnicov I've already addressed that, read the bottom part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @mechnicov  my bad I didn't paid attention to it.
I am able to generate the required json format in ruby. We can close this question

Comment: @Amey hmm, I read again and It is unclear for me